# How to Display/Visualize Images after Convolution and Relu in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, visualization, convolution

I have this code (during testing, not training) for my input image and first convolution and Relu layer:

```
convnet = input_data(shape=[None, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, IMAGE_CHANNELS], name='input')
convnet1 = conv_2d(convnet, FIRST_NUM_CHANNEL, FILTER_SIZE, activation='relu')
convnet1 = max_pool_2d(convnet1, FILTER_SIZE)
```

If I print the variable convnet1, I get this result **Tensor("MaxPool2D/MaxPool:0", shape=(?, 52, 52, 32), dtype=float32)** which is right because my input image is 256x256 and filter size is 5x5.

My question is how can I visualize my convnet1 data/variable? It has 32 channels so I'm assuming I can display 32 black and white images with dimensions 52x52.

Comment: You can average out the values from each channel and display the resultant 52x52 image.

Comment: yes I can do that so that I can just generate one image but I don't know how to write the code... I did some reshaping but it has errors.

Comment: Checking the dimensions is very crucial. It can be very irritating at first to find out where there is a need to flatten and so on, but with experience everything will be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print 32 of them in one plot you can do something like this

```
def plot_convnet(convnet, input_num=0):
    # since convnet1 is 4dim (?,52,52,32) Assuming the first dim is Batch size you 
    # can plot the 32 channels of a single image from the batch given by input_num

    C = Session.run(convnet) # remove the session run if the tensor is already 
                             #evaluated

    # Number of channels -- 32 in your case 
    num_chnls = C.shape[3]

    # Number of grids to plot.
    # Rounded-up, square-root of the number of channels
    grids = math.ceil(math.sqrt(num_chnls))

    #Create figure with a grid of sub-plots.
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(grids, grids)

    for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
       if i<num_chnls:
           im = C[input_num,:, :,  i]
           #Plot image.
           ax.imshow(im,                  
                     interpolation='nearest', cmap='seismic')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: In the line ax.imshow(img, vmin=w_min, vmax=w_max, interpolation='nearest', cmap='seismic') where is the variable 'img' coming from? or it's 'im'?

Comment: I have edited my answer, it was a typo `img` supposed to be `im` which is defined on the line above.

Comment: Hi @D.negn, how do I import Session in C = Session.run(convnet) ? It always gives me an error NameError: name 'Session' is not defined. If I declare another session using tf.Session(), then it gives me an error as well because it doesn't belong to the same graph.

Comment: By the way, I run and load my model via
model = tflearn.DNN(convnet_final, tensorboard_dir='log')
model.load(MODEL_NAME)

Comment: The tensor convnet1 which is printed as **Tensor("MaxPool2D/MaxPool:0", shape=(?, 52, 52, 32), dtype=float32)** needs to be evaluated using either `Session.run()` or `Tensor.eval()` . So you can evaluate it in your Session, call the function  `plot_convnet`  from inside the Session and remove the line `C = Session.run(convnet)` from  function.